# System Log does not load

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, syslog

The System Log GUI is not loading.  Appears in the side bar for a few moments and then disappears.  Captured this from `/var/log/apport`

```
ERROR: apport (pid 7668) Fri Jul 13 23:28:37 2018: called for pid 7662, signal 5, core limit 0, dump mode 1
ERROR: apport (pid 7668) Fri Jul 13 23:28:37 2018: executable: /usr/bin/gnome-system-log (command line "/usr/bin/gnome-system-log")
ERROR: apport (pid 7668) Fri Jul 13 23:28:37 2018: debug: session gdbus call: (true,)

ERROR: apport (pid 7668) Fri Jul 13 23:28:37 2018: this executable already crashed 2 times, ignoring
```

Tried re-installing the applet, but still did not resolve this issue.  The system-log has appeared previously as a crash report which I have forwarded.

```
Package in question:  gnome-system-log
Version: 3.9.90-4
Kernel: 4.4.0-130-generic
Release: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
```

Per request, the following is from `gnome-system-log-pkexec`:

```
(process:8407): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_param_spec_boxed: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_BOXED (boxed_type)' failed

(process:8407): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_class_install_property: assertion 'G_IS_PARAM_SPEC (pspec)' failed

(process:8407): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_param_spec_boxed: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_BOXED (boxed_type)' failed

(process:8407): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_class_install_property: assertion 'G_IS_PARAM_SPEC (pspec)' failed

(process:8407): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_param_spec_boxed: assertion 'G_TYPE_IS_BOXED (boxed_type)' failed

(process:8407): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_class_install_property: assertion 'G_IS_PARAM_SPEC (pspec)' failed

(process:8407): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: g_object_set_valist: object class 'GtkTextTag' has no property named 'paragraph-background-gdk'

(gnome-system-log:8407): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: g_menu_item_set_detailed_action: Detailed action name 'win.filter_Wireless Reassociation' has invalid format
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

=============================================================

Not sure if it is related, have come across Glib errors simply from going to the shell.

```
Jul  8 22:45:54 Upstairs console-kit-daemon[2551]: console-kit-daemon[2551]: GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 85 was not found when attempting to remove it
Jul  8 22:45:54 Upstairs console-kit-daemon[2551]: GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 85 was not found when attempting to remove it
Jul  8 22:46:32 Upstairs console-kit-daemon[2551]: console-kit-daemon[2551]: GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 92 was not found when attempting to remove it
Jul  8 22:46:32 Upstairs console-kit-daemon[2551]: GLib-CRITICAL: Source ID 92 was not found when attempting to remove it
```

---

Was scanning some old notes and noticed I had observed the following just prior to losing the System Log altogether.

"Turns out the GUI for systemd is buggy.

First, if I choose “Today”, it keeps kicking me out and transferring to Xorg log.

Second, the Filter generated a crash of the log app.  I was unable to cleanly send a report."

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `gnome-system-log-pkexec` in a terminal? Thanks.

Comment: Well -- I sort of solved the problem.

Elevated to root in the shell session, typed in gnome-system-log.

Not exactly the right answer -- but it appears to be permissions-related.  I never meddle with permission levels (never had to) on this workstation.  So the next question is whether this is where the permission failure is occurring.